# Parameterized input of file inside tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, input

I have looked into a few threads about passing arguments to \input command but haven't found much. Any help with my current predicament (or feedback of an alternative approach) would be appreciated! My current setup (working, but not ideal) is:

Relevant part from main.tex

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \input{grid}
    %some other shapes
\end{tikzpicture}
```

grid.tex

```
\draw[black!20!white] (0,0) grid (20, 20);
\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below left] {(0,200)};
\fill (20,0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {(200,200)};
\fill (0,20) circle (2pt) node[above left] {(0,0)};
\fill (20,20) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(200,0)};
\fill (20,20) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(200,0)};
\tiny
\foreach \x in {20, 40, ..., 180} {
    \fill (\x/10,20) circle (2pt) node[above] {\x};
}
\foreach \y in {20, 40, ..., 180} {
    \fill (0,20-\y/10) circle (2pt) node[left] {\y};
}
```

Although I'd like to customize the grid. Something like -

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{#1/10}
\draw[black!20!white] (0,0) grid (\inc,\inc);
\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below left] {(0,#1)};
\fill (\inc,0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {(#1,#1)};
\fill (0,\inc) circle (2pt) node[above left] {(0,0)};
\fill (\inc,\inc) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(#1,0)};
\fill (\inc,\inc) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(#1,0)};
\tiny
\foreach \x in {#2, #2*2, ..., #1 - #2} {
    \fill (\x/10,\inc) circle (2pt) node[above] {\x};
}
\foreach \y in {#3, #3*2, ..., #1 - #3} {
    \fill (0,\inc-\y/10) circle (2pt) node[left] {\y};
}
```

And input it in main.tex as:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \input{grid}[160][10][25]
    %some other shapes
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \input{grid}[300][15][15]
    %some other shapes
\end{tikzpicture}
```

EDIT:

MWE as requested by @Andrew (working, but not ideal) -

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \input{grid}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

grid.tex:

```
\draw[black!20!white] (0,0) grid (20, 20);
\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below left] {(0,200)};
\fill (20,0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {(200,200)};
\fill (0,20) circle (2pt) node[above left] {(0,0)};
\fill (20,20) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(200,0)};
\fill (20,20) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(200,0)};
\tiny
\foreach \x in {20, 40, ..., 180} {
    \fill (\x/10,20) circle (2pt) node[above] {\x};
}
\foreach \y in {20, 40, ..., 180} {
    \fill (0,20-\y/10) circle (2pt) node[left] {\y};
}
```

EDIT 2:

Taking suggestion given by @Andrew, I have managed to define variables in the main file and use the same in grid.tex

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \def\gridsize{300}
    \def\xMarker{45}
    \def\yMarker{50}
    \input{grid}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

grid.tex:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\size{\gridsize/10}
\draw[black!20!white] (0,0) grid (\size,\size);
\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below left] {(0,\gridsize)};
\fill (\size,0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {(\gridsize,\gridsize)};
\fill (0,\size) circle (2pt) node[above left] {(0,0)};
\fill (\size,\size) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(\gridsize,0)};
\fill (\size,\size) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(\gridsize,0)};
\tiny
\foreach \x in {0,\xMarker, ..., \gridsize} {
    \fill (\x/10,\size) circle (2pt) node[above] {\x};
}
\foreach \y in {0,\yMarker, ..., \gridsize} {
    \fill (0,\size-\y/10) circle (2pt) node[left] {\y};
}
```

Still hoping I can just pass the values to the file somehow :)

I don't think I can create a command since I can't put it inside tikz.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Ideally it should compile  unless, of course, that is what you are asking about.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not possible to pass arguments to `\input` in this way because `\input` is not really a macro and, instead, it simply includes the specified file. What you could do is define macros, say `\A, \B, ...`, in `main.tex` and then use these macros as "parameters" in the included file.

Comment: @Andrew Preferably with less dangerous names.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a macro other than `\input` i.e. define a new macro. But `\input` simply takes one argument. That is, it isn't that you haven't figured out how to use it with more parameters. There are no more parameters. And this is certainly not a macro you want to mess around redefining.

Comment: May I ask ***why*** you want to do it by inputting another file within the `tikzpicture`? It seems an odd thing to have your heart set on. Why not: define a macro to produce the grid? (Define it in another file if you like. Or not.) Or, better, perhaps, use a `pic`? (Define it in another file if you like. A Ti*K*Z library or not. Or not. As you wish.)

Comment: @cfr, would i be able to use the macro inside tikz? i tried using \NewDocumentCommand but seems like I can't use that inside tikz :(

Comment: @cfr, i want a template grid on which i can put more shapes for different files (writing exam papers for about 1000 students with different data sets)

Comment: @gauravgupta Sure. Even with `\NewDocumentCommand`. I'd go for a `pic`, but a macro is certainly an option.

Comment: @cfr - can you please redirect me to a learning resource on macro? sorry, not being lazy just that i am confused since there are so many resources and don't know which to choose.

Comment: 'macro' is just a catch-all term for all commands and the commands underlying environments and so on. So `\NewDocumentCommand` is a macro for creating a new macro, `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is a macro for creating two new macros (one for the beginning and one for the ending of the new environment). It is all macros unless it is just textual content ;).

Comment: So `\mygrid` is the new macro in my example below :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \mygrid { O {300} O {45} O {50} }
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\size{#1/10}
  \draw[black!20!white] (0,0) grid (\size,\size);
  \fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below left] {(0,#1)};
  \fill (\size,0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {(#1,#1)};
  \fill (0,\size) circle (2pt) node[above left] {(0,0)};
  \fill (\size,\size) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(#1,0)};
  \fill (\size,\size) circle (2pt) node[above right] {(#1,0)};
  \begin{scope}[font=\tiny]
    \foreach \x in {0,#2, ..., #1} {
      \fill (\x/10,\size) circle (2pt) node[above] {\x};
    }
    \foreach \y in {0,#3, ..., #1} {
      \fill (0,\size-\y/10) circle (2pt) node[left] {\y};
    }
  \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
  \mygrid[200][35][25]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
  \mygrid
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: variations on a grid]

Comment: Thanks @cfr! that is exactly what i wanted to do. funnily, when i tried it it didn't work (i didn't use scope - maybe that's why). Thanks a Tonne :)

Comment: @gauravgupta Did you get an error about a font due to the use of `\tiny`? `tikzpicture` sets all fonts to the 'null' font and then sets it back when typesetting the content of nodes. I'm not exactly sure of the specifics to explain why it is OK in the original code, but, when I got an error about font selection, I figured that was probably the culprit.

Comment: `font=\tiny` it will handle OK. I just used a `scope` to limit it to the relevant part of the picture, really. If you took the `\tiny` out, it also solved the problem, but, obviously the node labels were a bit big then.